# MongoDB - Get a field from all matching objects in an array?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have been migrationing mySQL to mongoDB.
I wanted to embed teaches, course table to instructor table.
I have a mongo database structure as follow.

```
{ 
"_id" : "14365", 
"ID" : "14365", 
"name" : "Lembr", 
"dept_name" : "Accounting", 
"salary" : 32241.56, 
"teaches" : [
    {
        "ID" : "14365", 
        "course_id" : "200", 
        "sec_id" : "1", 
        "semester" : "Spring", 
        "year" : 2007.0, 
        "course" : {
            "course_id" : "200", 
            "title" : "The Music of the Ramones", 
            "dept_name" : "Accounting", 
            "credits" : 4.0
        }
    }, 
    {
        "ID" : "14365", 
        "course_id" : "843", 
        "sec_id" : "1", 
        "semester" : "Fall", 
        "year" : 2010.0, 
        "course" : {
            "course_id" : "843", 
            "title" : "Environmental Law", 
            "dept_name" : "Math", 
            "credits" : 4.0
        }
    }
]
```

}

I want to query like the following SQL query.

```
SELECT name, title From instructor Natural join teaches Natural join course;
```

How I can query in mongodb?

Comment: What is your expected output? And what do you want to achieve, could you put that in words? Also could you give few sample documents from each collections?

Comment: I now want to output the title of the course with the same dept_name of the instructor from the double nested course object.

Comment: Please update the same in the OP, with examples. And I had asked for few sample documents from each collections, update it also in OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to MongoDB's aggregation operator [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Using project stage we'll project only needed fields */
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0, // _id is by default included - you need to exclude it
      name: 1,
      title: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$teaches", // Iterate on objects of `teaches` array
          initialValue: [], // Initial value
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.course.dept_name", "$dept_name"] }, // condition to check
              {
                $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this.course.title"]], // If condition is met push values to array
              },
              "$$value" // If not send same holding array back for this iteration
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fIjwpK9qDhF)

**Test :** `$filter`: [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J1iXpb5BbXR)

**Note :**

We've used `$reduce` to bring all title's from different objects in `teaches` array to an array. You can also use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to achieve similar thing. If in any case if your `title` is just a single element in array (no duplicate `dept_name` in `teaches` array) then you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) or [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to convert `title` array to string.

Comment: Can I ask additional questions? How can I get rid of the empty title array here?

Comment: @jieun: So empty on `title` means for that document no matches has been found - which is why `$filter` results in `[]` ! Do you want that doc in result without `title` field or don't you need that doc at all(like completely remove docs where `title : []`) ?

Comment: I think I need that doc at all(like completely remove docs where title : []).

Comment: @jieun : Ok, as you **don't need** that docs then you need to add `$match` as first stage `{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$dept_name",
          "$teaches.course.dept_name"
        ]
      }
    }
  }` , **Test :** https://mongoplayground.net/p/cqXf3VTZnwB , It will get only the docs where atleast one object in `teaches` array has matching `dept_name`.

Comment: I can’t thank you enough!!!! thank you so much. I solved all things thanks to you!!